# Can somebody please explain this react code to me? I can't seem to wrap my head around it

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function handleChecking(index) {
    const updatedTasks = tasks.map((task, i) =>
      i === index ? { ...task, checked: !task.checked } : task
    );

    updatedTasks.push(updatedTasks.splice(index, 1)[0]);

    
> if (!updatedTasks[updatedTasks.length - 1].checked) {
> updatedTasks.unshift(updatedTasks.pop());
>     }

    setTasks(updatedTasks);
  }
```

I need thorough explanation of the quoted code because I don't get it. The code was provided by ChatGpt and my todo-app works as I expected but I don't know why. Every task has a checkbox next to it and when I check that checkbox it moves to the end of an table of tasks(end of an array). That part I understand. Let's say I have 4 unchecked tasks at the beggining and 3 checked tasks at the end. When I uncheck the second to last task it goes to the top of the table(start of an array). From my understanding of the code it should not work like that. It should pop() only the last one since pop does that right? Anyways I tried asking chatGPT the same question and he than says I am correct and he refactors the code. And I am not gonna touch my code because it works as I expected. Please help because I want to know. I gotta know! I can't go around saying I have a functional app without knowing how everything inside it works.

I hope I provided enough code. If not, please say what more should I add. But I think this should be understandable to experienced developers.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. "Can somebody?" isn't a good question on SO.  Your title should be a clear, specific question about code.  Present your problem or question _before_ you dump code on us. Word to the wise: steer clear of AI solutions and don't mention them here. They're not reliable.

Comment: If the last element of an array (presumably of HTML checkbox inputs? I didn't really read the rest) is checked it takes it off the end of the array (pop) and puts it at the front (unshift). Paste `foo = [1,2,3]; foo.unshift(foo.pop()); console.log(foo);` into your browser console and you'll see `[3, 1, 2]`.

Comment: I would rather change the code to be something sensible. That code might work but as you noticed it’s hard to understand since it’s a very convoluted way of doing things and nobody would write such code themself. I suggest taking a moment to write the code yourself rather than taking such messy things from an LLM.

Comment: The indicated lines in your code first checks the "checked" flag on the task object whose flag was toggled in the initial loop and then which was moved to the end of the array by the `.push()` call. If the flag on that task object is not set, that means it *was* set before the initial loop, so the body of the `if` removes that from the end of the list (the `.pop()`) and pushes it onto the *front* of the list (`.unshift()`). That said, I would have written that function much differently. But then I'm not an AI.

Comment: Some documentation: [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

Comment: Also when you title a question, think about how your title content might enable somebody in the future to find your question based on the specifics of what you're asking. In this case, that might include something about what `.unshift()` and `.pop()` do when used together. "Help me understand a thing" is not really useful to anybody.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on my bad question wording. I will try to do better next time.

Comment: @Nixy no worries, everybody here was new at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I, a human, would implement that function. It's less computation and easier to understand (in my opinion beep boop):

```
function handleChecking(index) {
    const target = tasks[index];
    target.checked = !target.checked;
    const first = !target.checked;

    const updatedTasks = [];
    if (first)
      updatedTasks.push(target);

    for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; ++i)
      if (i !== index)
        updatedTasks.push(tasks[i]);

    if (!first)
      updatedTasks.push(target);

    setTasks(updatedTasks);
}
```

Only one loop, only one new array created, no new objects created, no splicing, no unshifting, also clearer. In my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function handleChecking(index) {
      //A checking task handler
        const updatedTasks = tasks.map((task, i) =>
        //checks for index which matches 'index' parmateter
          i === index ? { ...task, checked: !task.checked } : task
          //if it finds the exactly the option that user checked then returns the current task edited {...task, checked:!task.checked} means it returns the task with all its properties and edit the checked to false of the current state that means if the current option is checked then it unselect that and if it is not then selects that. If the current index doesn't match the 'index' parameter then returns task meaning current option unedited.
        );
    
        updatedTasks.push(updatedTasks.splice(index, 1)[0]);
        //It pushes the checked task to the last of the list. First splice() method deletes the element by taking index of the item and number of elements to delete as parameter. Here index means the current option's index and 1 means only one element needs to be deleted from 'index' serial. splice() returns an array containing the deleted element. Here it returns the array of only one element which is the current option. To get the element [0] used to define the first element of the returned array. push() pushes the element to the last of the list.
    
        
    > if (!updatedTasks[updatedTasks.length - 1].checked) {
    ///checks if the last task is checked or not if not then pushes that to the beginning of the tasks using unshift() and removing it from the last using pop(). pop() returns the element that was removed and unshift() takes the element as parameter which is to be added at the beginning.
    > updatedTasks.unshift(updatedTasks.pop());
    >     }
   
        setTasks(updatedTasks);
        //This is most important mentioned in your code updating the task. using useState updates the state for tasks this one of the coolest feature from ReactJS. I'm enclosing proper links that is helpful for you. here
      }
```

Some useful links:

1. [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

2.[push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

3.[splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

4. [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)
5. [useState() hook](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Hope you find it helpful.